# Create a Status column based on the payment behavior of each account

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am currently working on automating some of our manual tasks. I am very new in Python and I would like to request your help. I have the following dataframe:

```
    account_id  contract_id 2021-01-01 |  2021-02-01  |  2021-03-01  |  2021-04-01
0   account1    contract11  200.0         200.0          200.0          NaN 
1   account1    contract12  NaN           300.0          300.0          300.0   
2   account1    contract13  NaN           100.0          100.0          100.0   
3   account1    contract14  NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN 
4   account2    contract21  500.0         NaN            NaN            NaN 
5   account2    contract22  NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN 
6   account3    contract31  NaN           NaN            NaN            250.0
```

I want the following output (with a new column 'status'):

```
 account_id contract_id |   status    | 2021-01-01 |  2021-02-01  |  2021-03-01  |  2021-04-01
0   account1    contract11  Original    200.0         200.0          200.0          NaN 
1   account1    contract12  Upgrade     NaN           300.0          300.0          300.0   
2   account1    contract13  Downgrade   NaN           100.0          100.0          100.0   
3   account1    contract14  Renewal     NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN 
4   account2    contract21  Original    500.0         NaN            NaN            NaN 
5   account2    contract22  Winback     NaN           NaN            NaN            NaN 
6   account3    contract31  Original    NaN           NaN            NaN            250.0
```

Each account can have at least one contract.

It's "Original" if it's the first contract that has the first payment.

It's a "Winback" if a contract was made after 4 months of no payments from the previous contract.

It's an "Upgrade" if the contract has monthly payments greater than the previous contract.

It's "Downgrade" if the contract has payments smaller than the previous contract.

It's "Renewal" if the contract has payments equal to the previous contract.

I tried the following code (uses date activated column) but it does not work properly:

```
def get_types(monthly_payments):
    def f(s):
        check = monthly_payments.loc[
            (s.date_activated.year == monthly_payments.index.year) &
            (s.date_activated.month == monthly_payments.index.month)
            ].iloc[0]

        if check.wb == 0:
            # If rolling sum of 4 months prior is 0
            s['status'] = 'Winback'
        elif check.og_upg == 0:
            # If Prior Month is 0
            s['status'] = 'Original'

        elif check.max_pmt > check.og_upg:
            # If Prior Month is not missing and current month is more
            s['status'] = 'Upgrade'
        else:
            s['status'] = 'Renewal'
    return f

def apply_types(g):
    # Get Non Payment Info
    account_info = g[g.columns[:4]]
    # Transpose Monthly Payments To Rows
    monthly_payments = g.loc[:, g.columns[4:]].T
    # Make Sure Index is DT
    monthly_payments.index = pd.to_datetime(monthly_payments.index)
    # Get Check for is early based on number of payments
    monthly_payments['early'] = monthly_payments.astype(bool).sum(axis=1) > 1
    # Max Payment In Month
    monthly_payments['max_pmt'] = monthly_payments.max(axis=1)
    # 1 Month Prior
    monthly_payments['og_upg'] = monthly_payments.max_pmt.shift().fillna(0)
    # Rolling Sum of 4 Months Prior
    monthly_payments['wb'] = monthly_payments.max_pmt \
        .rolling(min_periods=0, window=4).sum().shift()
    # Concat New Columns With Original Payment Information
    return pd.concat((
        account_info.apply(get_types(monthly_payments), axis=1),
        g[g.columns[4:]]
    ), axis=1)

df = df.groupby('account_id', as_index=False).apply(apply_types).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first reshape your df into long form for easier manipulation. Start with `stack` on your original df to get rid of the `nans`, rename the columns and also cast `date` into `datetime`:

```
df = (original_df.set_index(["account_id", "contract_id"]).stack().reset_index()
                 .rename(columns={"level_2":"date", 0:"amount"}))
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
print (df)

   account_id contract_id       date  amount
0    account1  contract11 2021-01-01   200.0
1    account1  contract11 2021-02-01   200.0
2    account1  contract11 2021-03-01   200.0
3    account1  contract12 2021-02-01   300.0
...
18   account3  contract31 2021-04-01   250.0
19   account3  contract31 2021-05-01   250.0
20   account3  contract31 2021-06-01   250.0
```

Now we can do it step by step with assigning first contracts of each id to `original`:

```
df.loc[df["contract_id"].eq(df.groupby("account_id")["contract_id"].transform("first")), "status"] = "Original"
```

Next, set up your different requirements and use `np.select`:

```
cond1 = df["contract_id"].ne(df["contract_id"].shift())
cond2 = df["date"].diff().dt.days>=120
cond3 = df["amount"].diff().gt(0)
cond4 = df["amount"].diff().lt(0)
cond5 = df["amount"].diff().eq(0)
cond6 = df["status"].isnull()

df["status"] = (np.select([cond1&cond2&cond6, cond1&cond3&cond6, cond1&cond4&cond6, cond1&cond5&cond6],
                          ["Winback", "Upgrade", "Downgrade", "Renewal"], df["status"]))
```

Finally assign the result to your original df:

```
original_df["status"] = df.groupby(["account_id", "contract_id"])["status"].first().tolist()
print (original_df)

  account_id contract_id  2021-01-01  2021-02-01  2021-03-01  2021-04-01  2021-05-01  2021-06-01  2021-07-01     status
0   account1  contract11       200.0       200.0       200.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   Original
1   account1  contract12         NaN       300.0       300.0       300.0         NaN         NaN         NaN    Upgrade
2   account1  contract13         NaN       100.0       100.0       100.0       100.0       100.0       100.0  Downgrade
3   account1  contract14         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN       100.0       100.0       100.0    Renewal
4   account2  contract21       500.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   Original
5   account2  contract22         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN       300.0       300.0    Winback
6   account3  contract31         NaN         NaN         NaN       250.0       250.0       250.0         NaN   Original
```